# Correct method of passing an array to constructor method in Java?

Tags: java

I am new to Java, coming mainly from C++ & JS, and I am just experimenting trying to learn the differences and what not and I came across something unusual. I am trying to pass an array of doubles into a constructor method, but the way I was trying would not work. The method signature for the ctor is

`public Student(int sid, String name, double [] grades)`

The way I was trying to pass the array was

`Student s1  =  new Student(1, "Mike", [99.9,88.8]);`

however the only way i could get it to work was by creating an array
`double[] grade = {99.9,88.9}` and passing that to the ctor  like `Student s1 = new Student(1, "Mike", grade)`

So my question is, is it possible to do it the way i first tried 
`Student s1  =  new Student(1, "Mike", [99.9,88.8]);` or something similar?

Thank you.

@ernest_k did you even read my question before closing it? the thread you linked was a completely different issue.

Comment: `new Student(1, "Mike", new double[] { 99.9, 88.8 })`

Comment: Oh i didnt realize i had to use the new specifier there. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline It wont work when i do that that's what i dont understand. Cause my ctor looks like that

Comment: @d0rf47 I completely failed to modify the constructor! Let me try again: If you modified the constructor to `public Student(int sid, String name, double... grades)` it would still work with array but you could write `new Student(1, "Mike", 99.9, 88.8)`.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline wow thats amazing! thank you so much! that is exactly what i was looking for!